# ubi-partman failed with exit code 10 during 12.10 fresh install

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, windows-xp

ive been trying to install ubuntu 12.10 on my acer aspire one 534h,using an iso from the official site and a 16gb flash drive using unetbootin. my aa1 is running factory settings (xp). it will boot fine from the usb, but the installation throws the error in the title after choosing my wifi options, and contineus to give the error after every subsequent step. after trying to complete the installation ingoring the error, it hangs on the ask ubuntu screen. ive tried reformatting and reflashing (sorry, heavy android user) ubuntu to the flash drive, to no avail... do i need to format somthing else, or is it something to do with th Hdd and RAID drives? ive looked in my BIOS and found nothing related. only the option for sata or ide... any help would be great, as ive been working at this all day...

edit: 
the error message was ubi-partman has failed with exit code 10. see (gave a directory) for more info. it then informed me that if i continued the install could be incomplete or completly broken. not sure abouth the wording in the second part, but the error is word for word...

thank you.

Comment: what was the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during boot to see additional options. Choose `nodmraid`. See [the community BootOptions page on Ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions).

Comment: For me installing Lubuntu, pressing F6 and ticking nodmraid made this work.