# Can I run Ubuntu "Alongside" my Windows on the Hard disk?

Tags: 13.10

I have been trying to put Ubuntu on my 8gb flash drive, while already having it on a 4gb and not having enough space. I don't want to deal with it any more. When it said I could install Ubuntu alongside my windows, I don't know how that works. Can I chose which one I want to boot, when I go to the F12 menu? Or does that even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps.A complete manual. This shows how to install ubuntu from a usb stick.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick

And to create bootable pendrive, i prefer using "Universal Usb installer" It's simple  to use.

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

steps to create bootable pen drive:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Problem, I'm not sure if it's working with my Windows 7 starter. It gives me a error message after I click continue, when it makes sure I have enough memory and internet, etc. in the install for Ubuntu.  The error message: ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. Further instruction may be found in /var/log/syslog  When I click "continue anyway" it goes strait to the "Where are You" Setup, without asking if I want to install Alongside or etc.

Comment: Try this: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/248500/ubi-partman-failed-with-exit-code-10-during-12-10-fresh-install

Us the command nodmraid 
It was suggested in yet another post also.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1498417

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu alongside windows and choose which one do you want to boot on startup.

[Windows Dual boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Comment: I just found out that you don't HAVE to use cd's. I can do the same DaulBoot setting install through my flash drive. I can do that, right?