# I need help installing and using ubuntu

Tags: installation, wubi

I'm new here! I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit version just now. It downloaded in .RAR (Winrar). When i open the file, i have many folders in it and at last, i have this "wubi.exe" file. i double-click it and it extracts. But after extraction, nothing rally happens. Sometimes i get the windows error sound but no pop-up box comes on the screen.

My second question, should i install it on my harddrive(with my windows) or a dvd, or a pendrive? What to do? Can someone give me a complete guide on ubuntu? Never used.

And also, i forgot my bios password, so i can't enter into bios. is that a problem? Can anyone help me on this too?

If there's anything i need to know, please tell me :)

Comment: Officially Ubuntu is released as an .iso file. Where did you download from? I suggest you download from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Also read installation instructions in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Comment: i downloaded it from their official website.

Comment: did you use mirror?I have never seen a .rar file officially

Comment: i don't know.i downloaded it from here:http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Yeah, sorry! My mistake. it is .iso file but it downloads in winrar. i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser settings and check how it downloads `.iso` files. set it in such a way that it downloads the file directly as it is and stores it somewhere.

Once done this,mount the file on a cd/dvd/usb.
All you need to know next is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).
Also there is some possibility that you will boot into black screen.If so read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).
And lastly,for all the basic problems you will mostly probably fall into,the [frequent questions page](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=frequent).

And not to forget,the **bios password won't matter at all**.should not until you wish to break your computer with wrong bios settings.

Comment: for firefox,it's edit->preferences->applications.

Comment: I think it would be a little difficult for me. I'm just a kid. But still, let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, it is an iso file, and since you don't have any software to mount iso files, Winrar automatically shows the iso file types as winrar files. Don't worry. 
Use a free iso mounter software like Daemon tools.
You can get the free version here.

http://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtLite#features

After installing it now see the file you have downloaded. The icon may be changed. If not no problem. Open Daemon tools from start menu and choose "Mount" option. Then browse for the file you have downloaded and select mount. Now you can see the files inside that iso file in "My Computer". Use WUBI installer to install. And for further assistance,
Follow the link aditya patil posted.

Comment: Now see, I burnt the .iso file to my dvd with astroburn lite. I also had it in my usb drive. But, then after burning, when i restart, nothing happens, it just boots to windows xp. In my BIOS, my boot drive is my had drive in which windows xp is there. So, i guess i would have to change it to my optical drive to boot through ubuntu, isn't it?But, i lost my BIOS pass, so what should i do to change it? And what exactly is wubi? whenever i open it i get an error sound of windows.

Comment: While booting do you get any comment like Press (key) to select boot device? And ofcourse without changing the boot priority to either CD/DVD drive or USB device it will be automatically booting into Windows.

Comment: Follow this link to install Ubuntu alongside Windows from a Usb device.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/404601/can-i-run-ubuntu-alongside-my-windows-on-the-hard-disk/404660?noredirect=1#comment520108_404660

Comment: You see @assassin, I first start my computer, i get my some G31TM-P21 page, which is my motherboard. Then i just get windows xp and then the welcome page (after inserting my passowrd for windows). And no, i don't get any comment like press any key to change the boot drive .

Comment: Then you should try to recover your Bios password. Google it to find how to recover a lost Bios Password.

Comment: Many say to clear the password by jumping the battery, but i'm just a kid and if i do something wrong, then i'm dead!

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I suppose you would have to change your boot sequence in order to install Ubuntu through a USBstick, or pendrive like you said, but I'm not sure if you'll be able to do it without the BIOS password. So let's stick with another option.

You can use a DVD burning software to burn a DVD with the Ubuntu .iso file. After that, all you need to do is insert the disc and install.

But, since you're using Windows, I guess it would be much more simple if you just use a Windows Installer for Ubuntu instead of the .iso file.
You can get the installer in this page: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

And the installation instruction here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Unfortunately it's not available for Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10.

If you still want to try a .iso file installation I recommend you to take a look at the others two articles (How to burn a DVD - How to create a bootable USB stick) you can find in that last page I posted here (right of the page).