# /boot/grub/grub.cfg has two different Linux versions and lost windows loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8, alienware

I'm running a UEFI dualboot Alienware system (Windows 8.1 - Ubuntu 16.04) using grub2.
After a normal dist-upgrade, i found the new kernel update '4.4.0-57' which should replace '4.4.0-53'. However, i lost the windows 8.1 entry in Grub2 and now I can only boot Ubuntu, update-grub didn't work for me; I checked /boot/grub/grub.cfg and it gave me this.

[grub.cfg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRmyv.png)

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Boot-repair summery
http://paste2.org/GOGjKmNP

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub` ? If that does not work. May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Yes I've tried > Sudo update-grub

Comment: http://paste2.org/GOGjKmNP Here is the boot-info report

Comment: Do you have SSD and is it RAID? http://askubuntu.com/questions/795755/grub-problems-on-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-using-samsung-950-pr
 and: Kernel 4.6 has Dell & Alienware improvements including 9350
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-4.6-Laptop-Drivers May be better to use newer version of Ubuntu to get newer kernel.

Comment: Yes, I have SSD and it is RAID, I have the latest version of Ubuntu 16.04 already..

Comment: 16.10 uses the 4.8 kernel. RAID is an issue. You probably need to change to AHCI to get grub to install. You may then be able to turn the RAID back on, but be sure to have good back ups. You can try boot parameters like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760257/ubuntu-16-04-failed-clean-install-on-new-hard-drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update-grub` script *should* be picking up the Windows boot loader, since it *is* present, as shown here:

```
sda2:
__________________________________________________________________________
    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi
```

Note the presence of `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`, which is the Windows boot loader. My initial hypothesis is that a bug in the `update-grub` script is causing it to omit the Windows boot loader for some unknown reason. Two workarounds spring to mind....

**Option #1**

Open the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file in a text editor and add the following lines to it:

```
menuentry "Windows 8.1" {
    set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
    chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Note that these lines are customized to your specific system and may need to be adjusted should somebody else need to implement this fix. The `(hd0,gpt2)` specification, in particular, identifies where the Windows boot loader files live. Also, there are many variants on this boot entry that may be tried. Doing a Web search on custom boot entries in GRUB may be informative.

With this file edited, type `sudo update-grub` and check `grub.cfg` or reboot to see the effect. With any luck, a GRUB 2 entry for Windows will be added and will work. If the entry does not work, then any error messages GRUB emits when you try the entry may be informative.

**Option #2**

This workaround is predicated on the assumption that the Windows Fast Startup and/or Hibernate features is causing subtle filesystem damage that's causing `update-grub` to fail. Thus, the goal is to disable these Windows features. To do so, though, you must first boot to Windows. In the process of making the attempt, you'll also test another boot manager that might work better than GRUB, even if filesystem damage is not the cause of the problem. To try this approach:

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (Download links for both are on that page.)
2. Prepare a boot medium from the file you download.
3. Reboot to the rEFInd boot medium. (You'll probably need to use your firmware's boot manager to get it to boot to the removable medium, much as you presumably did when installing Ubuntu.)
4. rEFInd *should* show you entries for both Windows and Ubuntu. If so, boot to Windows.
5. In Windows, disable both Fast Startup and Hibernate, as described [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html), respectively.
6. Reboot to Ubuntu.
7. Try `sudo update-grub` again.
8. If that still doesn't work, but if rEFInd gave you the option to boot Windows, install rEFInd using its PPA or Debian package. This will make rEFInd the default boot loader; since it worked, this step bypasses the still-problematic (for you) GRUB in favor of the working (for you) rEFInd.

If rEFInd does not show an option to boot Windows in step #4, or if that option doesn't work, then the problem is deeper than it appears from your Boot Info Script output. My guess if that's the case is that the Windows boot loader file has become damaged. If you happen to have a backup, restoring the file from the backup may fix the problem. If not, you should ask on a Windows forum about recovery.

Comment: Thank you so much, your first option worked instantly! Much respect.