# Couldn't install 18.04 LTS on Dell XPS 8900

Tags: system-installation, kernel, dell

I'm using a XPS 8900 to install Ubuntu on. When I press "something else", the installer gets stuck loading forever. The only error message I can find is 
`kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80`and I have no idea what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Also Just noticed that the screen is frozen after about 10-20 minutes of loading.

Comment: First thing to do is update UEFI. SSDs often need firmware update too. Then try again. If the same error you may need additional boot parameters and/or if you don't need TPM (in dual-boot Windows), better disable it.

Comment: Almost all Dell need UEFI update, if SSD, firmware update and setting for drives changed from RAID or Intel SRT to AHCI. If dual booting with Windows add AHCI driver to Windows first. Some older threads:  Installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 on Dell 8930 with dual boot win10
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413145
 Dell XPS 8910: 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2351949
Dell XPS 8900 i7-6700 pcie_aspm=off http://askubuntu.com/questions/760257/ubuntu-16-04-failed-clean-install-on-new-hard-drive
Black Screen Dell XPS 8900 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So. This answer is *very* late, but I was recently having some other unrelated issues with installing Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 on the same system and when researching I found this question I forgot I asked years ago. I guess this makes me a senior developer!? /j

Anyway, the solution was adding `pcie_aspm=off` in the kernel boot params in grub (either by editing the params in grub itself or editing "./boot/grub/grub.cfg" and repackaging the ISO. My final command was as follows:

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper pcie_aspm=off nomodeset ---
```

Adding `pcie_aspm=off`, obviously, solved the error this question talks about.
Adding `nomodeset` fixed another error I was running into with the desktop environment because I was using an Nvidia GPU.
I also removed `quiet splash` because I was coming across a weird bug I couldn't reproduce reliably on another machine that was fixed by removing `quiet splash`. I still don't know how or why that works, but it does so I've been doing it for all my machines since just in case.

Also, *this needs to be reproduced for the installed system as well*. The first time I boot into the OS I just installed, I edit the same params and once I'm in the OS I edit the grub config file the same way to make the change persistent.

Read more:
https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/issues-with-installing-Linux-on-an-XPS-8900/td-p/4666421

[Ubuntu 16.04 failed clean install on new hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760257/ubuntu-16-04-failed-clean-install-on-new-hard-drive)