Unable to boot Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from live USB
Whenever I click the "Try Ubuntu" button after loading Ubuntu from a live USB, the OS crashes and I get this error message:
[  0.083287] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this
RMRR [0x0000000079800000-0x000000007bffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
[  0.356071] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover t
[  0.356101] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover t
[  2.128728] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 3bbaec

I understand that this error is generated when the firmware throws an error the kernel does not understand and is usually the result of graphics driver incompatibilities.
My machine is an Dell XPS 8900 desktop. There are no other hard drives, SSDs, or additional persistent storage attached to the computer besides the bootable USB.
I have tried:

The nomodeset boot option
Booting Ubuntu in safe graphics mode
Turning off secure boot, fast boot, and SGX in my BIOS settings.
Using 20.04 LTS and 24.04 LTS
all of the above in combination

I have been able to use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on this machine before.

This question is similar to: Firmware Bug on Boot Up Ubuntu 22.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also: Dell XPS 8900 i7-6700 pcie_aspm=off (also: Asus X555UB)
http://askubuntu.com/questions/760257/ubuntu-16-04-failed-clean-install-on-new-hard-drive While older, it may still apply. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303880

@stumblebee I think it's different as I get the impression that Lauren can't boot. Although there are a few info messages that can be ignored (similar to the flagged duplicate), the last message looks like an error

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@moo What baffles me is the OP was able to run 22.04 which made me think this most likely points to a BIOS setting (Even though OP changed settings). Using acpi=off boot option also crossed my mind. I also found this which is what @oldfred mentioned - pcie_aspm=off
